# I am now reading tags from XML how do I read from multiple arrays

Tags: php, xml

I have it reading XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PLAYER name="RadioBOSS" version="6.2.4.2">
<TRACK ARTIST="Ivy" TITLE="While We&#39;re In Love" ALBUM="Long Distance" YEAR="2001" GENRE="Lush; Indie Rock; Indie Pop;" COMMENT="http://mp3caprice.com" FILENAME="C:\Music &amp; Video\Ivy -  2001 Long Distance\Ivy - 05 - While Were-In Love.mp3" DURATION="04:34"  STARTED="2023-03-03 08:26:50" PLAYCOUNT="20" LASTPLAYED="2023-03-03 08:26:50" INTRO="258.28" OUTRO="0.00" LANGUAGE="" RATING="10" BPM="48" TAGS="" F1="" F2="" F3="" F4="" F5="" CASTTITLE="Ivy - While We&#39;re In Love" LISTENERS="0" />
<PREVTRACK><TRACK ARTIST="Abel" TITLE="Onderweg" ALBUM="De Stilte Voorbij" YEAR="2000" GENRE="Folk" COMMENT="" FILENAME="C:\Music &amp; Video\Abel - Onderweg.mp3" DURATION="03:12"  STARTED="2023-03-03 08:26:50" PLAYCOUNT="53" LASTPLAYED="2023-03-03 08:23:43" INTRO="0.00" OUTRO="0.00" LANGUAGE="" RATING="0" BPM="192" TAGS="" F1="" F2="" F3="" F4="" F5="" CASTTITLE="Abel - Onderweg" /></PREVTRACK>
</PLAYER>
```

How do I reference first TITLE in this XML?

Comment: Please edit your question, remove the `var_dump()` and replace with the actual xml string.

Comment: H Jack,  I tried     $artist =iconv( "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT",$xml->TRACK->ARTIST);    echo $artist; as i wondered if it was not showing anything because of character set differences but it still provides no output so i must be doing something wrong in my access of it ?

Comment: Have i got to normalize this to JSON to be able to read it ? https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

Comment: So just to confirm: you're working with PHP and your expected output is `"While We're In Love"`?

Comment: yes PHP Jack I have no answer yet if anyone can help please ? have i got to normalize this to JSON to get out values  I am using simplexml_load_file which has given mulitple arrays which are really confusing to get data from as i never learned any of this

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need json for this - just xpath and simplexml.

Try this:

```
$contents = 
<<<END
[your xml above]
END;
$xml_data = simplexml_load_string($contents);
$title = $xml_data->xpath('//PLAYER/TRACK/@TITLE');
echo $title[0];
```

Output:

```
While We're In Love
```

Comment: Thank you.  but am using $xml=simplexml_load_file("images/nowplaying.xml"); I tried this as you wrote 

    $title = $xml->xpath('//PLAYER/TRACK/@TITLE');
    echo $title[0];
    $artist =$xml->xpath('//PLAYER/TRACK/@ARTIST');
    echo $artist;
    $album = $xml->xpath('//PLAYER/TRACK/@ALBUM');
    echo $album;

but got no output

Comment: I had to use $title = implode($xml->xpath('//PLAYER/TRACK/@TITLE'));

Comment: i still dont think its injecting this into SQL I dont know why as implode should make it a string

Comment: @PPFU It seems your sample xml in the question is not an accurate representation of `nowplaying.xml`. The code in the answer works as expected with the sample.

Comment: ok I had to adjust it slightly  $title = implode($xml->xpath('//PLAYER/TRACK/@TITLE')); I am using simplexml_load_file to allocate xml how do i deallocate this as currently getting snap errors from to much memory allocation

Comment: @PPFU Why are you using `impolode()`?

Comment: Because it works like that :D and not without .